# Imagick gives wrong width and height of gif?

Tags: php, imagemagick, gd, imagick

I m using Imagick for image processing but for 1 gif image my Imagick gives wrong
width and height.
[this is that image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEx4k.gif)

> https://i.gifer.com/O7gC.gif

my code

```
$image = new \Imagick('O7gC.gif');
$image->getImageWidth();     // gives 1px
$image->getImageHeight();    // also gives 1px
$image->identifyImage();     // [geometry]['width'], and height is also 0
```

but

> getimagesize() gives correct information.

Other images are working fine just this single image not working ?

and setting

```
$image->mergeImageLayers(\Imagick::LAYERMETHOD_FLATTEN);
```

gives correct width and height, i can't understand this behaviour please explain ?
i m using imagick

phpinfo imagick

```
Imagick compiled with ImageMagick version : ImageMagick 7.0.7-11 Q16 x64 2017-11-23 http://www.imagemagick.org

Imagick using ImageMagick library version : ImageMagick 7.0.7-11 Q16 x64 2017-11-23 http://www.imagemagick.org
ImageMagick release date : 2017-11-23
```

Answer (score 4):

The internal image stack iterator is pointing to the last GIF frame read. For `07gC.gif` the last frame is a single pixel. When working with formats that have optimized layers, either reset the internal iterator to the first frame (in GIFs this would be the largest bounds), or coalesce all frames (reverse the layer optimization).

```php
$image = new \Imagick('O7gC.gif');
$image->setFirstIterator();
```

.. or ..

```
$image = new \Imagick('O7gC.gif');
$image = $image->coalesceImages();
```

Comment: can a single gif can have different - different size of frames ? are the valid according to specification ?